# Quit condition on Terraform blueprint

Tags: terraform

I want to have a terraform blueprint that quits given a certain condition at the top.

If the `var.available` is set to false, I want the blueprint to stop everything and throw an error. What is the syntax for this? I cannot find it in the doc files anywhere. Does this functionality even exist in terraform yet?

Note: this code is in a .tf blueprint file

**My code:**

```
available_ports = "${var.available ? 1 : quit_here}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround to stop the Terraform script from executing based on a condition. All it needs is a null_resource:

```
resource "null_resource" "condition_checker" {
  count = "${var.variable == 1 ? 0 : 1}"
  "Insert your custom error message" = true
}
```

This workaround is explained by [Jamie BitFlight](https://github.com/Jamie-BitFlight) here: [Ability to raise an error #15469](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15469)

There is limitation to this workaround. It does not work with `-target` enabled while running Terraform.

Comment: A little ugly, but if terraform doesn't have that functionality built in, I guess an ugly workaround is my only option.

Answer (score 0):

If you use terraform v0.13.0 or later you can use pre and post conditions.

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  ami           = data.aws_ami.example.id

  lifecycle {
    # The AMI ID must refer to an AMI that contains an operating system
    # for the `x86_64` architecture.
    precondition {
      condition     = data.aws_ami.example.architecture == "x86_64"
      error_message = "The selected AMI must be for the x86_64 architecture."
    }

    # The EC2 instance must be allocated a public DNS hostname.
    postcondition {
      condition     = self.public_dns != ""
      error_message = "EC2 instance must be in a VPC that has public DNS hostnames enabled."
    }
  }
}
```

Se more here [developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

If you use terraform v0.13.0 or later you can use pre and post conditions.

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  ami           = data.aws_ami.example.id

  lifecycle {
    precondition {
      condition     = data.aws_ami.example.architecture == "x86_64"
      error_message = "The selected AMI must be for the x86_64 architecture."
    }
    postcondition {
      condition     = self.public_dns != ""
      error_message = "EC2 instance must be in a VPC that has public DNS hostnames enabled."
    }
  }
}
```

Se more here [developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions)