# Is it possible to report error on a condition with terraform 0.12?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Original reference - [Quit condition on Terraform blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388902/quit-condition-on-terraform-blueprint)

Is it still possible to make conditional check like in the above question

```
resource "null_resource" "condition_checker" {
  count = "${var.variable == 1 ? 0 : 1}"
  "Insert your custom error message" = true
}
```

Similar format does not work in terraform 0.12 and 0.13 and I could not find any reference to removal of this feature. Is it possible to make a check like this 0.12 or 0.13?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you wanting to do variable validation? If so 0.13 introduced variable validation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#custom-validation-rules. It was also technically included as far back as 0.12.20 behind a feature flag if you are unable to upgrade to 0.13 yet: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.12/CHANGELOG.md#01220-january-22-2020

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is to validate the current workspace with a defined workspace - something like terraform.workspace != var.workspace throw an error.

Comment: Why are you asking for the workspace at all then instead of just using the value from `terraform.workspace`? You should still be able to check that the variable is set to `terraform.workspace` with input validation though.

Comment: when you store the state in remote and use workspace to differentiate the key, it is very easy to make a mistake. Say I switched to workspace "one" and trying to run the script for workspace "two". But I figured, terraform is pretty solid in avoid those kind of mistakes and the differences when I tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to here was never an actual Terraform feature, but rather an example of exploiting a bug in an earlier version of Terraform to get a result that Terraform had no explicit support for.

With that said, modern versions of Terraform have support for [custom variable validation rules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#custom-validation-rules) which allow you to write out variable validation checks directly inside the corresponding `variable` block. For example:

```
variable "variable" {
  type = number

  validation {
    condition     = var.variable == 1
    error_message = "Variable value must always be 1."
  }
}
```

With that said, I just copied your contrived example from the question here, so this would require some adaptation for a real example. Note also that variable validation rules can only depend on the variable value and other constants, so you can't use this for more complicated checks such as those which involve two different variables. For that sort of situation, I'd recommend refactoring so that the values that are related arrive in a single variable of a object type, and then the validation can be for whether that object is valid.

Comment: As I mentioned in the above comment, I was trying validate the terraform.workspace variable with an input variable. As you have mentioned I may not be able to do this as variable validation does not allow any other variable to be mentioned in the block. Considering this is the most we can do at this point, I am going to accept this as the answer.

Comment: This upcoming feature looks very close to what I was asking I think - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/25088

Comment: Unfortunately there seems no progress with the feature :-(

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is still not possible to validate inputs that require access to more than a variable. (The `validation` block only allows access to the validated variable.)

A hacky validation is still possible using the `external` data source:

```
data "external" "check_valid" {
  count = var.to_test == true && some_other_condition ? 1 : 0
  
  program = ["sh", "-c", ">&2 echo Condition must be satisfied when to_test is true; exit 1"]
}
```

This condition is checked before terraform asks for approval of a plan.

On the output it looks like this:

```
Error: failed to execute "sh": Condition must be satisfied when to_test is true


  on variables.tf line 1, in data "external" "check_valid":
  1: data "external" "check_valid" {
```